# Heap space - memory administration

Tags: java, linux, sockets, memory, synchronization

We have an application that once a day is using the entire allocated heap memory.
I made a memory dump of heap space, to help me find the cause of this problem that it's available on this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwMd9KDnQRfQT3dzRTZfUWdjMU0/view?usp=sharing.
I believe that application is poorly implemented, or it may be something related to DB4O technology, and its objects sent between client and server, or connections that are open to the server after users sync data between their systems and server.
The service did not provide error: Out Of Memory: heap space, but I follow your resource allocation to say that.

I am starting the application with this shell script...

```
set +x

export BRANCHOFFICE_HOME=/bat/orquestra/branchoffice/live18
cd ${BRANCHOFFICE_HOME}
echo BRANCHOFFICE_HOME = ${BRANCHOFFICE_HOME}

# classpath
OQT_CLASSPATH=${BRANCHOFFICE_HOME}/classes/:${BRANCHOFFICE_HOME}/classes/branchoffice.jar

for libFile in ${BRANCHOFFICE_HOME}/lib/*.jar
do
  OQT_CLASSPATH=${OQT_CLASSPATH}:${libFile}
done

export OQT_CLASSPATH
echo OQT_CLASSPATH = ${OQT_CLASSPATH}

# JVM arguments
JAVA_ARGS=-server
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Xms2048m"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Xmx2048m"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -XX:+UseLargePages"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Duser.country=BR"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Duser.language=pt"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -cp "${OQT_CLASSPATH}
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=synchengine.SynchEngine"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1207"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file="${BRANCHOFFICE_HOME}"/config/passwordFile"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file="${BRANCHOFFICE_HOME}"/config/accessFile"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.acl.file="${BRANCHOFFICE_HOME}"/config/acl"
JAVA_ARGS=${JAVA_ARGS}" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
export JAVA_ARGS
echo JAVA_ARGS = ${JAVA_ARGS}

# APP arguments
export APP_ARGS=${BRANCHOFFICE_HOME}/config/SynchEngine.xml
echo APP_ARGS = ${APP_ARGS}

echo Starting Synchronization Engine
```

I would like to have any tips or support, because the application is very large.

Server...

- Architecture:          x86_64
- CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
- Byte Order:            Little Endian
- CPU(s):                4
- On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
- Thread(s) per core:    1
- Core(s) per socket:    1
- Socket(s):             4
- NUMA node(s):          1
- Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
- CPU family:            6
- Model:                 42
- Stepping:              2
- CPU MHz:               2294.472
- BogoMIPS:              4588.94
- Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
- Virtualization type:   full
- L1d cache:             32K
- L1i cache:             32K
- L2 cache:              256K
- L3 cache:              15360K
- NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
- Linux version 3.0.101-0.21-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Mon Apr 7 12:32:42 UTC 2014 (172cdff)
- Java version: 1.5.0_22 x64
- DB4O version: 6.1

Need any more information I am available, grateful to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to close your sockets connections..

Looking into your dump, your sockets connections is never closed, allocating unnecessary memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use JVisualVM (in the java directory) to profile the application while running. Then you can see the total memory usage and can also watch the memory footprint of different kinds of objects.

Comment: The application uses the Java version 1.5, and unfortunately we can not change the version of Java for that reason, because another supplier is the server administrator.

Comment: So you tried to run the application with Java 1.7 or 1.8 and it failed?

Comment: No, locally using these versions of Java it works, but doesn't occur lack of memory. We did not get what occurs on the server in our environment.

Comment: This is a difficult situation, but I would set up a test environment, put as much load as possible on the program and monitor the memory with the profiler of JVisualVM. Then one can see what kind of objects use most of the memory. Changing the code to fix this issue may be hard, though.